# sqlite3 CLI - abort current query

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3 command line tool on a windows cmd.exe shell.
Is there a way to abort the current query?
`[ctrl] + c` exits the program completely to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for an equivalent to the MySQL `\c`, then, no, unfortunately there is no such command.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?